# javascript and Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, internet-explorer-8

I have a jsp page which is using JavaScript for automatic selection in onload page event 
and some jQuery to dynamically expand different div tags with some content inside.

So the problem is that the calling of the `setSelection` method, which is in the bottom of the page in script tags, and the jQuery methods which are in a js method called `toggle` doesn't work at all in IE8. However in Chrome, Firefox and IE9 it works fine.

I've Googled this issue a lot but I can't find anything useful. The only errors which the debuger tool in IE8 show me are "Object required" and "Expression required".

Here is the code:

```
                        <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function toggle(el)
                {
                    var val = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
                    if (val == "1")
                    {
                        document.getElementById("2").style.display = "none";
                        $("#1").slideToggle(250);
                    }
                    else if (val == "2")
                    {
                        document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
                        $("#2").slideToggle(250);
                    }
                    else if (val == "0")
                    {
                        document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("2").style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
                function setSelection(selection) 
                {
                    //Here we make dynamic selection of the combo box
                    var selct = document.getElementById("sel");
                    selct.options[selection].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
                    toggle(selct);
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <select name="mySel" id = "sel" onchange="toggle(this);">
            <option value="0">Zero</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
        <div id="1" style="border:1px;">
        </div>
        <div id="2" style="border:1px;">
        </div>
        <script>
            setSelection(0);
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Go to the computer with the code and post it on jsfiddle so we can help ya

Comment: Do you have a link to the site or is it only local?

Comment: @Rey He should also post it here.  Linking to third party sites is a bad idea because SO cannot be certain they will last forever.  If jsFiddle disappears, this question will mean nothing to future readers.

Comment: no problem but is far away from me. I'll try to make a similar code and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in document ready function and try.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready. Use $() w/o colliding with other libs;
});
```

Comment: it works fine now I jsut have to understand why the content of the div tags doesn't want to show. Thanks :)